# Word that encompasses pixel and voxel

Tags: image, image-processing, video-processing, terminology

Is-there a word that generalizes the notion of pixel and voxel to any dimension ?
Similarly, for superpixel / supervoxel.

Referring to "superpixel or supervoxel" for a method that can operate on both isn't quite nice. Especially if I am not tied to the dimension, and it could be "voxel+time" or "supervoxel+time" etc. Any commonly accepted term ?

Comment: Pixel (2D) and voxel (3D) generally refer to something that can be visualised. If you have an n-dimensional data set that's not visual data, you should use domain-specific terms or just mathematical "a point in n-d space" or "a vector in n-d space" etc.

Comment: pixel/voxel mostly refer to the notion of square/cubic element in a grid, while a superpixel/supervoxel is a group of them... That's not either a point in n-d space... For instance, if we have a tomographic 3d reconstruction that is discretized regularly in time : how are these 4D elements called ? These are neither "spatiotemporal points" since these are not points, nor voxels since they are 4D....

Answer (score 1):

Superpixel already has a meaning in regular use, and it's not what you want:
http://www.csd.uwo.ca/~olga/Projects/superpixels.html

The term "n-xel" isn't something I'd want to use around the office. I have a need to use a term for a 4D element, but it won't be "doxel"--on a noisy communication line it would sound too much like "voxel". "n-xel" isn't something that trips lightly off the tongue, and might even generate some unfortunate spray onto one's colleagues.

If you don't mind confusing dimensionless points with elements that have spatial extent, "4D point" works. In this case you might think of "4D" as "four degrees of freedom" rather than "four spatial dimensions."

"Hypervoxel" isn't pretty, but might work given we have cube and hypercube.

I kinda like "fourxel" pronounced like "FORKS-ull."

Eliminate the "x" which from "picture element" --> "pixel" (which some folks once also called "pel") and you might have "four D element" and so on:

- Fourdel
- Fivedel
- Sixdel
- ...
- Ndel?

Good luck!

Comment: It'd be even more entertaining if "fourxel" were pronounced like "forecastle" (i.e. "fo'k's'l")!

Comment: @Steve, I'm going to try "forecastle" (FOX-el) in an engineering meeting and see if it flies. Or rather, floats.

Answer (score 0):

The correct answer for the next dimension is "doxel." It appears at the very end of the Wikipedia article on voxels. Google thinks it's a dog and a drug but if you include "4d" in your search it does have academic journal use.

As for arbitrarily high dimensions, there seems to be no consensus other than maybe n-xel with n being any number.

Comment: that seems tied to 3D+t (hence "dynamic voxel"), Perhaps n-cell would work, though highly connoted from topology.

Answer (score -1):

Look at the etymology: pixel = picture element, voxel = volume element. Given that a picture is 2D space and volume is 3D space I think the best term would be "space element", or  "spaxel". I just made this up on-the-spot.

Interestingly, after a 5-second Google search Wiktionary actually supports this definition: http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/spaxel

> Blend of space and pixel, introduced in the 2012 paper Spaxels, Pixels in Space: A novel mode of spatial display (Horst Hörtner, Matthew Gardiner, Roland Haring, Christopher Lindinger, Florian Berger).

Comment: I did some google search looking for pixel voxel generalization but haven't found. Thanks!  This might not handle the notion of time, but might be enough for me.

Comment: ouch, sorry - I unvalidated you answer : spaxel adds the notion of motion in space (in their paper) and actually looks like "any variable attached to any point in space", which is not the concept that I'm looking for. And if this term is taken to mean something else, I just can't use it.